# How to mute/unmute Windows 10 Phone

Tags: lumia, lumia-640-xl

OK, did read the Global Mute in Win8, but how would it be in Win10? Didn't find any way for it.

Answer (score 3):

Press volume up (or down), tap on the icon to the left of the volume scale (you may need to expand the volume control panel if you want to mute both the ringer and in-app sounds).

Worth also noting that the phone will maintain separate volume levels for different outputs (headset, bluetooth, in-built speaker, etc.)

Comment: @Roland Shaw OK, this is known, but I'm after some kind of Global Mute, not this Volume+-mute, because, the volume knob is very easily touched by accident and then relieving the mute without noting it, and then the phone may ring loudly on a quiet place/situation ...Another symptom my sister is having is, that the ring is totally muted even pressing the knob here or there, so, what then may cause this? And, previously some years ago on some phones, there were a ring-tone "quiet" to be choosen, how about this today?